# What does $[-1,1]\times\{0\}$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What does the following notation mean? 
$$[-1,1]\times\{0\}$$ Does that mean all the elements of the form : $(a,0)$ where $a\in [-1,1]$?

PS: $[-1,1]$ is an interval on real line.

Comment: You're probably correct.

Comment: It is in a Topology book. @JoelReyesNoche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I expect your interpretation is correct.
$$
[-1,1] \times \{0\} = \{(a,0): a \in \mathbb R,\ \text{and } |a| \le 1 \}
$$
But, personally, I think this is a somewhat unhelpful notation for this set. It requires the reader to stop and think a little bit, which is always undesirable.

Also, note the use of "\times" rather than "x" (which Azarel has now corrected in your question).

Comment: Thank you! I will keep that in mind.