# Notation meaning $ X\times [0, M]$ and $Y \times \{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I'm having trouble understanding some notation.

Given a set $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $M>0$ for example, what exactly does

$ X\times [0,M]$ mean?

Or a taking a set $Y$, what does

$Y \times \{0\}$ mean?

This may be completely trivial but could someone explicitly state what this notation means in either case?

I understand that $[-1,1]\times \{0\}$ means all elements of the form $(a,0)$ where $a\in[-1,1]$ from another question but I'm unsure how to apply it to these two. 
([What does $[-1,1]\times\{0\}$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502972/what-does-1-1-times-0-mean))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X\times [0,M]$:

$\times$ is the Cartesian product and $[0,M]$ is the interval $\{x:0 \le x \le M\}$.

So, $X \times [0,M] = \{(x,r):x \in X \land 0 \le r \le M\}$

---

For $Y \times \{0\}$:

$\times$ is also the Cartesian product.

So, $Y \times \{0\} = \{(y,0): y \in Y\}$.

Comment: Thanks so much! For the first one do you mean $0 \le r \le M$ 
instead of $y$? Is the wedge just a mathematical way of saying 'and'?

Comment: Yes, corrected; yes.